# how to get google-updated version of the specified location in mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis using java

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

Suppose mybusiness is an initializer of type MyBusinessBusinessInformation which also takes care of credentials, and locationName is a String which refers to the specific location and its format is locations/XXXXXXX.
 [I am using this link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations/getGoogleUpdated)

```
   try {

         MyBusinessBusinessInformation.Locations.GetGoogleUpdated updateList=mybusiness.locations().getGoogleUpdated(locationName);                     
           GoogleUpdatedLocation response = updateList.execute();
          if(response!=null && !response.isEmpty()) {
                               System.out.println(response.toString());
                           }
   }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
   }
```

The error is

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the error detail: {
  "code" : 400,
  "details" : [ {
    "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"
  } ],
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}

Comment: Could you try issuing the request via the OAuth playground (https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request)? The Java client libary currently does not offer the detailed error information that the API would actually return.

Comment: @vpriesner thanks a million , the error is "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "read_mask", 
            "description": "Field is required"
          } but what are all possible read_mask?

Comment: Ok I understood,  just like locations list.       String readMask="storeCode,regularHours,name,languageCode,title,phoneNumbers,categories,storefrontAddress,websiteUri,regularHours,specialHours,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions,latlng,openInfo,metadata,profile,relationshipData,moreHours";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Vprienser I found out the read_mask is obligatory.

```
String readMask="storeCode,regularHours,name,languageCode,title,phoneNumbers,categories,storefrontAddress,websiteUri,regularHours,specialHours,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions,latlng,openInfo,metadata,profile,relationshipData,moreHours";

   try { 
        MyBusinessBusinessInformation.Locations.GetGoogleUpdated updateList=mybusiness.locations()
                                   .getGoogleUpdated(locationName).setReadMask(readMask);
                                
         GoogleUpdatedLocation response = updateList.execute();
                           
        if(response!=null && !response.isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println(response.toString());
           }
   }catch (Exceptions e){
    System.out.println(e);
   }
```